# Hidden Variables

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Currently in my asp.net app there is a textbox that is being assigned to a variable as a `Session Variable` I need to use a different method of storing the data and I was told to look into `Hidden Variables`

However, I have no clue how to use or assign them, can anybody give me some insight on how to use them?

Comment: Use a [`HiddenField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield(v=vs.110).aspx) and it's [`Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield.value(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of hidden variables.  If there isn't value in having it as markup then just use js variables or data attributes

Comment: @Rob A What's so bad about hidden variables?

Comment: Data in Hidden variables will be stored just on one specific page for one specific request. Session variable will be stored across all pages during this session. Do you still need them?

Comment: Why do you need to store the value differently?

Comment: @AdamZuckerman If I have two sessions up at once it stores both values and it messes up the data entries

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov The data is only used in one page, but the variable gets passed around in a couple different classes

Comment: A session is unique to a logged in user. A logged in user with two browser tabs on the same tab is not two unique sessions. You would want to use ViewState for single page instance data.